# Здраствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы книги отображались каждая в отдельной колонке

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image: Вот кусок кода]

```
import React from 'react';
import BookCard from './BookCard';
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Books.css';

const BookList = ({ cards }) => {

  const bookList = cards.map((i) => {
    let thumbnail = i?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail;
    return (
      <BookCard
        key={i.id}
        thumbnail={thumbnail}
        title={i.volumeInfo.title}
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="Book_page">
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>{bookList}</Col>
          <Col>{bookList}</Col>
          <Col>{bookList}</Col>
          <Col>{bookList}</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
};

export default BookList;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните вашу проблему. Из того, что я вижу, у вас книги и так стоят по одной в колонке

Comment: Изменил, поменял скриншот.

Comment: Вы 4 раза отрисовываете то, что по сути является контейнером для всего списка ```<Col>{bookList}</Col>```, а нужно, как я понял 1. Можно убрать лишние отрисовки, и самому контейнеру задать display: flex, отступы и т.д.